# Склеить пару строк с числом

Tags: строки, c++

Подскажите где и почему возникает ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_path(char* path, int day, char* exe) {
    char buffer[20];
    char *d = itoa(day,buffer,10);
    char *result = new char[strlen(path) + strlen(exe) +  strlen(d) + (int)1 ];
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    std::cout << get_path("/work/`PL0", (int) 5, ".m3u");

    return 0;
}

welcome.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':  
welcome.cc:43:56: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]  
     std::cout << get_path("/work/`PL0", (int) 5, ".m3u");  
                                                        ^  
welcome.cc:43:56: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Запуск:

ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ FAILED (значение выхода -1 073 741 511,, общее время: 52ms)

Решено, использую такой вариант:

```
std::string get_path(int day) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "/work/`PL0"<< day << ".m3u";
    std::string mystr = ss.str();
    return mystr;
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Вы только warning показали. Ошибок нет, если не считать дикую утечку памяти и предположительное отсутствие половины логики в get_path.

Comment: ну ошибка в том что это всё не выполняется, вторая строка это ошибка, нормально сюда нельзя текст выложить пробелы все удаляются ничего не будет понятно

Comment: Все нормально выкладывается. Если что то не так - поправим.

Comment: Что-нибудь с stdafx.h  наверняка. Во всяком случае в выложенном коде его нет, а VC++ очень уж его любит

Comment: обновил топик  
компилятор gcc(g++) 4.8.1 mingw  
а где утечки?

Comment: Так при чём тут это предупреждение при компиляции, если программа падает уже потом, при запуске? Если код именно такой как приведён в посте - это не удивительно, функция get_path() не может в принципе ничего делать, кроме как ронять программу...

Comment: вот код на питоне, мне нужно сделать тоже самое на C++ (оказалось это для плюсов оочень сложная задача)  
  
    patch = "/work/`PL0" + str(5) + ".m3u"  
  
как же мне решить столь не простую головоломку?!

Comment: @hitman249: Это не для плюсов, простите, сложная задача.

Comment: @VladD, ясно

Comment: @hitman249, проблема с `warning` решается просто:

     char* get_path(const char* path, int day, const char* exe) {
         ...

Вообще же `itoa` лучше не использовать (например, в Linux ее нет) и заменить на `snprintf` (или `asprintf`), да и и в includ-ы в дополнение к 

    #include <stdlib.h>

стоило бы добавить парочку

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно пойти в лоб

```
char path[256];
sprintf(path, "/work/`PL0%d.m3u", 5);
```

**upd**

более с++ вариант

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "/work/`PL0"<< n << ".m3u";
    // для вывода это преобразование не нужно, но мало чего там нужно будет
    std::string mystr = ss.str();
    std::cout << mystr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для современных версий C++ (C++11) проще всего воспользоваться идиоматическими строками:

```
auto s = string("/work/`PL0") + to_string(5) + string(".m3u");
```

Пруф: http://ideone.com/MbSuoO

Для старых версий языка проще всего, вероятно, решение [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) с `sprintf`.

Comment: только не забудьте сказать, что здесь с++11, и auto в начале не очень так...

Но в целом - хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim: Угу, указал. Многие пишут лабораторные работы до сих пор на древних компиляторах.

---
Впрочем, исходя из `/data/...`, думаю, у ТС `gcc`.